# show/hide 3 or more text blocks in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like a code that shows/hides 3 or more text blocks in javascript. I found this solution here [Show/Hide On Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213357/show-hide-on-click) but only works with 2 blocks of text.

html:

```
<a onclick="showText('text1','text2')" href="javascript:void(0);">Show Text 1</a>
<div id="text1" class="hide"> text1 </div>
<a onclick="showText('text2','text1')" href="javascript:void(0);">Show Text 2</a>
<div id="text2" class="hide"> text2 </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.hide { display:none; [your properties]; }
div.show { [your properties]; }
```

Javascript:

```
function showText(show,hide)
{
document.getElementById(show).className = "show";
document.getElementById(hide).className = "hide";
}
```

How can I fix it to make it works for 3 of more texts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, this function will show/hide any number of elements by adding necessary classes:

```
function showText(showElements, hideElements)
{
 for (var i=0;i<showElements.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById(showElements[i]).className = "show";
 }

 for (var i=0;i<hideElements.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById(hideElements[i]).className = "hide";
 }
}
```

First parameter is an array that contains element ids that you want to show, and second is another array for the ones you want to hide.

Usage:

```
showText(['id1', 'id2'], ['id3', 'id4']);
```

Comment: The above code does not work . showText(['id1', 'id2'], ['id3', 'id4']); It displays two ids at a time on a single click. It does not hide id2. And what is meant by "usage"?